# Python : How to contrast contrast data

Tags: python, math

I don't know what is the term for this, but what get the closest to it is the process of contrasting an image.

Basically i have a list of values going from 0 to 100. I would like that values over 50 come closer to 100 and values under 50 come closer to 0.

for example :

[0, 23, 50,58,100]

would become something like this (roughly) :

[0, 10, 50, 69, 100]

is their a mathematic formula for this ?

Comment: [0, 0, 100, 100, 100] according to your explanation this should be the output, right?

Comment: no i just want the values to go away from 50, but not becoming either 0 or 100, just like contrast

Comment: This is under-specified. Why should 23 go to 10 and not 20? Why should 58 go to 69? You haven't come close to articulating any clear rule behind these decisions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code might give you some ideas. If it doesn't meet your needs then you need to clearly explain just what those needs are.

```
def contrast(nums):
    contrasted = []
    for num in nums:
        if num < 50:
            contrasted.append(num//2)
        elif num > 50:
            contrasted.append((num + 100)//2)
        else:
            contrasted.append(num)
    return contrasted

data = [0, 23, 50,58,100]
print(contrast(data))
```

Output: `[0, 11, 50, 79, 100]`